# Which galaxies can sustain life as we know it - earth like life..?

Tags: radiation

When i view stellar telescope photos of our surrounding nearby and distant galaxies and stars - its a lot of them which emits an extremely strong light in various frequencies - from high energy cosmic radiation to high level infrared light.

Is there a standard for performing life sustain calculations regarding the various galaxies - and does it exist any ´visible universe map´ that shows both life supporting galaxies and galaxies where life is practically impossible due to to much high energy radiation and light...?

Comment: Hello Bengt, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. You're asking multiple questions, which is contrary to our procedures in the [help] and [tour]. If you had to ask one question (and you can only ask one question), which would it be? (a) Which galaxies can sustain life as we know it? (b) Is there a standard for [characterizing life viability] for galaxies? (c) Is there a "visible universe map" that shows life-supporting/non-life-supporting galaxies? ***Please [edit] your question to clarify which question you're asking,*** and remember to modify both the title and the body of the question. Thanks!

Comment: @JBH I would take it as primarily asking c) is there a map showing life supporting galaxies. With secondary b) can such a map be made. With c) being a graphical answer of a)

Answer (score 1):

**The largest galaxies have the highest life bearing potential**

The solar wind of Sol overwhelms the interstellar medium at a distance of 11 billion miles so developing life is protected from ordinary stellar radiation. The crucial factor in determining life viability would be object density - the chances of another object getting close enough to gravitationally interfere with a solar system, the chances of a gamma ray burst or supernova damaging a developing planet. The centre of any galaxy where the object density is much higher will present a much higher chance of this kind of interference and is therefore much less hospitable to life. In small galaxies where dense star clusters are wrapped around a small galactic hub it is much less likely that life will develop to an advanced stage. In very large galaxies with massive galactic discs there is a much higher chance that life will develop to an advanced stage and the chance gets higher as you get further towards the edge.

If you want a kind of formula, check these out: https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2014/11/complex-life-may-be-possible-only-10-all-galaxies

https://medium.com/amazing-science/hypotheses-on-the-distribution-of-life-in-galaxies-7f648cec80e9

Proximity to a high energy cosmic body such as Eta Carinae (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_Carinae) or an active black hole would also make a star system inhospitable, but these would be localised phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the wrong question We can't even tell necessarily if applied is capable of containing life  When we see it in our own Galaxy much less in another Galaxy.

The commonality or rarity of life in the universe is a hotly debated topic. The short answer we don't know. We don't know if there is even Intelligent life in our Galaxy much less in others. The problem is we have really one single sample size us. And until we find another will be hard to calculate exactly what Is neededbFor intelligent life form how likely Are they to develop technology,  how likely are they to go extinct and so on.   It should be noted however that given what we think the age of the Galaxy is and given what we think the size of the Galaxy is we should have been colonies by now by  an advanced civilization from another Galaxy.  The fact that we have not  Would suggest that we are alone in the universe however  There is currently no way to  Know for certain.